# Can we put image in the bootstrap table cell?

Tags: html, json, bootstrap-table

Can we put image in the bootstrap table cell?

I need data from JSON file and want to image in html table.

Comment: You may want to include a code sample of what you have so far or put it on https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I am still investigating, how can we put image in bootstrap table without using <img> tag. and taking image file location from static json data. No code sample till now.

Comment: Issue resolved. we used Actionformatter to show the image in table http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/39/

Comment: Another link https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/issues/579.html#L51

Comment: @BBB - if solved, put a self answer and accept it so this SO post marked solved